# Ascending chain of proper submodules in a module all whose proper submodules are Noetherian

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian, finitely-generated

Let $M$ be a module over a commutative ring $R$ such that every proper submodule of $M$ is Noetherian, then is it true that every ascending chain of proper submodules of $M$ terminate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this would imply the module is Noetherian.

Consider the [Prüfer $p$-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group), all of whose proper submodules are finite, but which is not Noetherian. The subgroups are linearly ordered, by the way.